# Filebeat does not collecting logs?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

## Problem

Ubuntu 18.04. The logs for some files not sending. For example I have has 16 log files on 2020-06-23. But only #5 & #8 got collected into `data.json`. Others are not found in `data.json`

Here's a script I use to found files on disk but not in `data.json`.

```
sudo python -c '
import json; import os; 
raw = os.listdir("/path/to/my/logdir")
f = open("/var/lib/filebeat/registry/filebeat/data.json", "r")
data=json.load(f)
harvested=[d["source"].split("/")[-1] for d in data]
substraction=[x for x in raw if not x in harvested]
print("\n".join(substraction))
'
```

The script result, there's just a lot:

```
app-2020-06-21.20.log
app-2020-06-21.25.log
app-2020-06-23.11.log
app-2020-06-22.1.log
app-2020-06-22.48.log
app-2020-06-21.41.log
app-2020-06-23.15.log
...
```

And there are only 2 types of logs `End of file reached` and `Non-zero metrics in the last 30s` :

```
Jun 23 12:23:12 filebeat[32738]: 2020-06-23T12:23:12.223Z        DEBUG        [harvester]        log/log.go:107        End of file reached: /path/to/my/logdir/app-2020-06-21.43.log; Backoff now.
Jun 23 12:23:12 filebeat[32738]: 2020-06-23T12:23:12.344Z        DEBUG        [harvester]        log/log.go:107        End of file reached: /path/to/my/logdir/app-2020-06-22.9.log; Backoff now.
Jun 23 12:23:12 filebeat[32738]: 2020-06-23T12:23:12.364Z        DEBUG        [harvester]        log/log.go:107        End of file reached: /path/to/my/logdir/app-2020-06-21.34.log; Backoff now.
Jun 23 12:23:12 filebeat[32738]: 2020-06-23T12:23:12.444Z        DEBUG        [harvester]        log/log.go:107        End of file reached: /path/to/my/logdir/app-2020-06-23.5.log; Backoff now.
Jun 23 12:23:15 filebeat[32738]: 2020-06-23T12:23:15.144Z        INFO        [monitoring]        log/log.go:145        Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":350,"time":{"ms":10}},"total":{"ticks":1710,"ti
Jun 23 12:23:45 filebeat[32738]: 2020-06-23T12:23:45.144Z        INFO        [monitoring]        log/log.go:145        Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":350,"time":{"ms":9}},"total":{"ticks":1720,"tim
Jun 23 12:24:15 filebeat[32738]: 2020-06-23T12:24:15.144Z        INFO        [monitoring]        log/log.go:145        Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":360,"time":{"ms":6}},"total":{"ticks":1740,"tim
Jun 23 12:24:45 filebeat[32738]: 2020-06-23T12:24:45.144Z
```

## Details

### Filebeat config

```
output:
  logstash:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - x.x.x.x:5044

filebeat:
  inputs:
    -
      paths:
        - "/path/to/log/dir/*"
      document_type: myapp
      multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}'
      multiline.negate: true
      multiline.match: after
      clean_removed: true
      close_removed: true

logging.level: debug

name: "myapp"
tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]
```

### Disk

Here's is the usage. I guess disk is fine

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...             2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
...             395M  820K  394M   1% /run
...              30G   12G   18G  41% /
```

Here's the inode checking result. You can see that there's no duplicated inode in `06-23` logs.

```
 ls -il * | grep 06-23
768289 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485996 Jun 23 00:33 app-2020-06-23.0.log
768372 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10486447 Jun 23 01:02 app-2020-06-23.1.log
768292 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485819 Jun 23 05:36 app-2020-06-23.10.log
800654 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10499153 Jun 23 05:59 app-2020-06-23.11.log
794052 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10486575 Jun 23 06:32 app-2020-06-23.12.log
768487 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10492683 Jun 23 06:59 app-2020-06-23.13.log
800633 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10490445 Jun 23 07:27 app-2020-06-23.14.log
794067 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10500849 Jun 23 07:55 app-2020-06-23.15.log
788191 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10489159 Jun 23 08:28 app-2020-06-23.16.log
788410 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10486744 Jun 23 09:30 app-2020-06-23.17.log
800624 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10486794 Jun 23 10:00 app-2020-06-23.18.log
794048 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10490002 Jun 23 10:39 app-2020-06-23.19.log
768461 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10486161 Jun 23 01:36 app-2020-06-23.2.log
794051 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10488204 Jun 23 11:12 app-2020-06-23.20.log
794081 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10487146 Jun 23 11:46 app-2020-06-23.21.log
794071 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10492866 Jun 23 12:16 app-2020-06-23.22.log
787673 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10490849 Jun 23 12:51 app-2020-06-23.23.log
787698 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3491076 Jun 23 13:00 app-2020-06-23.24.log
768478 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10486306 Jun 23 02:08 app-2020-06-23.3.log
768507 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10486690 Jun 23 02:34 app-2020-06-23.4.log
800620 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10496353 Jun 23 03:00 app-2020-06-23.5.log
800623 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10503668 Jun 23 03:36 app-2020-06-23.6.log
768521 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10520722 Jun 23 04:05 app-2020-06-23.7.log
774652 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10487379 Jun 23 04:38 app-2020-06-23.8.log
784704 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10553972 Jun 23 05:05 app-2020-06-23.9.log
```

Comment: Thanks, much better!

Comment: Yes it is @Arun. I put the golang tag last but it shows in the first place